# SQL constraint to exclude certain values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Is there an sql constraint that enables you to disallow certain values in a column?

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD COLUMN code TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE DISALLOW '<GENERATE>'
;
```

s.t. `<GENERATE>` could be used safely in the application to indicate that the value should be generated before persisting without risking its accidentally being pushed to DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
   ADD COLUMN code TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE;

alter table foo 
   add constraint disallow_generate 
   check (code <> '<GENERATE>');
```

If you want to disallowed multiple values, use a NOT IN condition:

```
alter table foo 
   add constraint disallow_generate 
   check (code not in ('<GENERATE>', '<GENERATED>', 'foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Check Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS).
eg:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD COLUMN code TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (code <> '<GENERATE>');
```